# How to insert widgets in Rich Text field

Tags: templating, editor

I want to insert widgets in arbitrary positions in one of my rich text fields. A good example would be a contact form inserted in the middle of the content. These widgets would be ad units, forms and similar dynamically rendered templates.

I know about the widget plugin for Redactor, but this is only suitable for static HTML. I need something a bit closer to an `{% include %}` tag.

How would you approach this problem?

I considered using WordPress-like `[insert-widget-here]` tags, or perhaps iFrames, but I'd prefer a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered using the [Matrix](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/matrix-fields.html) field type? You could create a block for rich text, then a block for a contact form (or whatever widget).

You could probably achieve what you're asking with a plugin but in my experience doing things like this in Redacter are prone to weirdness/bugginess (especially when in the hands of a client).

Comment: I would rather avoid that approach, as the content is logically a single unit: an article. At the moment, I use page breaks, which works fine for site-wide widgets (like ad units), but not so well for entry-specific widgets (like sponsors).

Comment: Perhaps I miss-understand but there needn't be any difference in the way it displays on the front end ie. the content can still look like:
<article>
    <p>You rich text output</p>
    <form>Your form</form>
    <p>More rich text</p>
</article>

Comment: Cutting the content in pieces with a Matrix field seems like the wrong approach. The content (e.g. an article) is a single unit and should be a single unit in the database. The widget is more akin to a bit of template: it contains server-side logic like a CSRF tag. It's not a static element.

Comment: In that case, it's a case of extending redactor.

Comment: @NicolasBouliane Cutting the article up into matrix blocks is an _excellent_ way to approach this problem. A matrix field is still a single field, I don’t understand what the hang up is.

Comment: This article describes the purpose and architecture very well... https://nystudio107.com/blog/creating-a-content-builder-in-craft-cms

Comment: Lindsey, you are right. I have simply misunderstood what a matrix field was. I've toyed around with it today and it's exactly what I need. Is there an easy way to migrate the content from a rich text field to a matrix field?